# having problems with removing sha1 encryption from my code

Tags: php, encryption

ill like to remove the sha1 encryption on this code so i can store my password as typed in the database instead of the encrypted code. Am new to coding so I need help

The code (settings_model.php)

```
    <?php
    $settings = new Datasettings();
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        $settings->$_GET['q']();
    }

    class Datasettings {

        function __construct(){ 
            if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                header('location:../../');   
            }
        }

        function changepassword(){
            include('../../config.php');
            $username = $_GET['username'];
            $password = $_GET['password'];
            $current = sha1($_POST['current']);
            $new = sha1($_POST['new']);
            $confirm = sha1($_POST['confirm']);
            $q = "select * from userdata where username='$username' and password='$current'";
            $r = mysqli_query($db,$q);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
                if($new == $confirm){
                    $r2 = mysqli_query($db,"update userdata set password='$new' where username='$username' and password='$current'");
                    header('location:../settings.php?msg=success&username='.$username.'');   
                }else{
                    header('location:../settings.php?msg=error&username='.$username.'');   
                }
            }else{
                header('location:../settings.php?msg=error&username='.$username.'');   
            }   
        }

        function addaccount(){
            include('../../config.php');
            $level = $_GET['level'];
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $q = "select * from $level where id=$id";
            $r = mysqli_query($db,$q);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
            if($level == 'student'){
                $username = $row['studid'];                
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $password = sha1($username.'-'.$fname);
            }else{
                $username = $row['teachid'];                
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $password = sha1($username.'-'.$fname);
            }
            $verify = $this->verifyusername($username);
            if($verify){
                $q2 = "insert into userdata values(null,'$username','$password','$fname','$lname','$level')";
                mysqli_query($db,$q2);
                header('location:../'.$level.'list.php?r=added an account');
            }else{
                  header('location:../'.$level.'list.php?r=updated'); 
            }

        }

        function verifyusername($user){
            $q = "select * from userdata where username='$user'";
            $r = mysql_query($q);
            if(mysql_num_rows($r) < 1){
               return true;
            }else{
                return false;   
            }
        }

        function getuser($search){
        include('../config1.php');  
            $user = $_SESSION['id'];
            $q = "select * from userdata where username !='$user' and username like '%$search%' order by lname asc";   
            $r = mysqli_query($db, $q);
            return $r;
        }


          function addaccounts(){
            include('../../config1.php');
           extract($_POST);

            $q = "select * from $level where id=$id";
            $r = mysqli_query($db,$q);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
            if($level == 'student'){
                $username = $row['studid'];                
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $password = sha1($username.'-'.$fname);
            }else{
                $username = $row['teachid'];                
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $password = sha1($username.'-'.$fname);
            }
            $verify = $this->verifyusername($username);
            if($verify){
                $q2 = "insert into userdata values(null,'$username','$password','$fname','$lname','$level')";
                mysqli_query($db,$q2);
                header('location:../'.$level.'list.php?r=added an account');
            }else{
                  header('location:../'.$level.'list.php?r=updated'); 
            }

        }



    }
?>
```

please help need an answer soon. thanks.

Comment: FYI: Don't use sha1, it's old and hackable. Use `password_hash()`

Comment: you're also mixing different mysql apis; you can't do that.

Comment: ***Pro tip:*** Do not act needy and do not say your requirement is urgent. The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the SHA1 encryption"? What are you replacing it with?

Comment: "How to write extremely insecure PHP password storing code?" would be an excellent title for this question.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security, cryptographic hashes are very fast. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score -1):

just change this line

```
$confirm = sha1($_POST['confirm']);
```

to this

```
$confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
```

Comment: Presumably, OP also must migrate the already existing passwords.

Comment: there is no reason it shouldn't have, this wont change any existing ones but any new ones put in it will.